# Different tax rate for B2B and B2C in magento 2

Tags: magento2, vat

We sell physical products in germany for individual and for companies (B2B) from Magento 2 website. For individuals, the tax rate is 19% and for B2B( ie if the customer enter company name & VAT) the tax is 0%.

I check the magento 2 documentation but could not find any links to have different rates for B2B and B2C. Can this be allowed from inside the Magento configuration ? Do we need to have use extension ? How can we achieve the same with custom code ?

Thx a lot
Laxman

Comment: B2B functionalities are achieved via native Magento Commerce modules, I assume, right? not a 3rd party b2b extension.

Answer (score 0):

All domestic businesses (B2B) and consumers (B2C) in Germany must pay VAT (Mehrwertsteuer).

A company in the EU (but not in Germany) with a valid EU Vat identification number may be invoiced with Zero VAT according to Intra-EU VAT rules. Similarly, companies outside the EU may also be Zero VAT invoiced.

Consumers and businesses in Germany must be invoiced with the correct VAT rate for the products or services offered.

Magento 2 has built in VAT Id validation see the official documentation for more information : https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/vat-validation.html

I can also recommend the following commercial module that extends the built in functionality and allows you to create customer groups and VAT rules for Domestic, Intra-EU and Worldwide trading : https://technology.pillwax.com/software/euvat-for-magento.html

Further information on how VAT Invoicing works in the EU can be found here : https://www.hellotax.com/blog/taxation/invoice-without-vat/eu-countries/